# How can I construct a lightweight privacy panel 3-4ft high by 8ft long or thereabout?

Tags: deck, partition

I have a two-story deck with the upper part on the roof, and I lay on top to sunbathe. The top was surrounded by a fence, but after installing solar panels close to the deck I removed a large part of the fence to avoid shading. I would like to find some lightweight portable panels three to four feet high so I can have privacy.

What I visualized is a rectangular tube frame with fabric stretched, and two flat bars attached at the bottom for feet. Three feet high would be best, but four foot max.

Comment: Remember google can still take your picture out there.

Comment: And drones, drones will also be able to see you.

Comment: I'm near an airport and planes fly over, too. I'm not naked. I just want privacy from neighbors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the systems that are used to hide A/C units? they are 3-4 feet high, attractive in appearance and you can link together as many as you wish. And when you want to take them down they are light and can be easily broken down and stored. They come in white, but with a little PVC paint they can become any color you desire.

Another option would be creating a frame with boards and attaching trellis boards.  With this option you can use hinges and make it fold for easy removal and storage.  You could also add some pretty artificial foliage for extra privacy.

Comment: I may just make some panels out of quarter inch plywood. If I make them 8x3 they won't be as heavy.